# getKikCodeUrl (kik-node) returns 404

Tags: node.js, chatbot, kik

I've started using the [kik npm](https://github.com/kikinteractive/kik-node) and got stuck with using getKikCodeUrl. When I pass an options object to it (as described in the npm github page and also in the [kik docs](https://dev.kik.com/#/docs/messaging)) I always get 404...
Anybody ever managed to get this to work ?

Here is the code snipet:

```
"use strict";

let util = require('util');
let http = require('http');
let Bot  = require('@kikinteractive/kik');

// Configure the bot API endpoint, details for your bot
let bot = new Bot({
    username: '***',
    apiKey: '***',
    baseUrl: 'https://***'
});

bot.updateBotConfiguration();

var options = {
    "data": "user scanned",
    "width": 250,
    "height": 250,
    "color": 13 // Royal Purple
};
bot.getKikCodeUrl(options).then((res) => {
    console.log("Got Kik Code");
});
```

And I always get:

> Unhandled rejection StatusCodeError: 404 - 404 Not Found. The resource could not be found.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if it matters, but I think "data" should be a dictionary.